# Jenkins generate the builds automatically whenever a pull request comes to bitbucket

Tags: jenkins

In The JENKINS:`Here I am trying to generate the builds automatically using bitbucket plugin in jenkins, I give the bitbucket url in jenkins source code repository and give the credential also`

`REPOSITORY URL:https://user:pass@bitbucket.org/sudinag/checking.git
Credentials:sudinag@bitbucket.org/********(checking)`
`I tick the build triggers:trigger builds remotely and i gave the api token also.`

In The BITBUCKET: Here i select the hook for the repository and select jenkins hook and i provide these details there

End point: `http://user:pass@192.168.1.5:8080 /jenkins.com/`
Project Name:maven
Token:sample_token`

In my system i have a git repository and i make some changes and pushed these,the operation is done successfully and and pushed but the jenkins doesn't generate the build .
`can you please help to me.`

Comment: Can bitbucket actually hit the endpoint you provided?  192.168.1.5 looks like a LAN address that can't be accessed from outside your network.

Comment: no it doesn't show any information in jenkins

Comment: ok,Alex can you guide me to rectify the above problem

Comment: As @Alex said, BitBucket can't reach the IP address that you gave it to trigger builds.  You will need to (or get a sysadmin to help you) set up an IP address for your Jenkins server that's accessible from the public internet.